# NetSuite SDF VS Code extension not working

Tags: json, visual-studio, netsuite, sdf

I am trying to get my VS Code extension for NetSuite SDFCLI to work and I have followed all of the directions and it keeps giving me an error that I cannot explain nor fix. In the debug mode of Code I am getting the error "Cannot find module 'vscode'. This appears to be a standard set of code that is in all VS Code extensions and for whatever reason this is just not working. I have done the npm install command and it still wont work. I have had two other developers look into the issue and they couldn't figure it out either. Ideas?[Screen Shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX7bo.jpg)